# ItemsSource in WPF Declaritively into C# Programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml

Quick question, how do I convert this into back end code? i.e. c#

ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource List1}, XPath=Entry}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Binding items = new Binding();
items.Source = FindResource("List1");
items.XPath = "Entry";
myItemsControl.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, items);
```

Where `myItemsControl` is the control on which to set `ItemsSource`.

Comment: I presume that the Entry element/node is going to contain a collection of children?